# how to use multiple initialization statements in javascript for loop?

Tags: javascript

how to use multiple initialization statements in javascript for loop?

can I use something like these below:

```
for(var i=0,j=0;i<5;i++,j++)
    console.log(i+":"+j);
```

I have used the above code but seems like its not working giving me an error,I have also tried with && operator like this

```
for(var i=0&&j=0;i<5;i++&&j++)
    console.log(i+":"+j);
```

Any suggestion would be helpful to me...Thanxx in advanced

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this? Given the fact that both initial values are set to `0` and both increment by `1` . . .

Comment: First example works fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: Your first code works just fine on chrome, firefox and edge. https://jsfiddle.net/wsavyv33/

Comment: maybe you have to use nested approach ...

Comment: i'm curious to see why who suggest a different approach gets downvoted...

Answer (score 0):

You can use comma operator:

```js
for(var i=0, j=0; i < 5; j++, i++) {
    console.log(i+":"+j);
}
```

Comment: function(params){
  var _super=this;
  try{
   var newObj={};
   for(var i=0, params.data=params.data.split("&");i < params.data.length;var p=params.data[i].split("="), i++){
    newObj[p[0]]=p[1];
   }
   return newObj;
  } 
  catch(e){
   typeof(params.onerror)=='function'?params.onerror(e):console.error(e);
  } 
  return _super;
 }

Comment: It works on FF and Chrome.. are you using any JS parser/compiler?

Comment: Strange.. `var _super=this;` - this line suggests that there is a  compiler used.

Answer (score 0):

Your first code snippet seems correct. What error are you facing in that code?

Also on a additional note use `let` instead of `var` especially in loops.

```
for(let i= 0, j =1; i < 3 && j < 3; i +=2, j++){
  console.log('I value : ' + i);
  console.log('J value : ' + j);    
}
```

Comment: function(params){
  var _super=this;
  try{
   var newObj={};
   for(var i=0, params.data=params.data.split("&");i < params.data.length;var p=params.data[i].split("="), i++){
    newObj[p[0]]=p[1];
   }
   return newObj;
  } 
  catch(e){
   typeof(params.onerror)=='function'?params.onerror(e):console.error(e);
  } 
  return _super;
 } This code is not working its also the same concept but with different statements

Answer (score 0):

For running `i` and `j` independently, you could use a nested approach.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        console.log(i + ":" + j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd keep the code simple.

```
j=0;
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
    console.log(i+":"+j);
    j=j+1;
}
```

you are getting the desired result but your code readibility is better : the for is related only to the i - the condition is only i<5 - so it is a good practice from my perspective to keep the j as a separate variable.

Having a limit condition also with j i'd use a nested for.